# How do I run logic at a exact time in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-service, alarmmanager, foreground-service

**Background and flow**:

I'm building the app for Android API 31+. (Tested on an Andorid 33/31 hardware)
My app should work as an alarm clock but with a logical check before sounding the alarm, the logical check uses data from the web that needs to be current at the time of the alarm.

- Currently im using the Alarmmanager to set the alarm.
- A BroadcastReceiver receives the alarm and then starts an foregroundservice running a thread that downloads some data from web.
- When the data is downloaded the thread sends a broadcast to the same receiver (but with different intent data).
- The BroadcastReceiver runs some logic checking that data corresponds with some params in alarm.
- If the logic checks out the alarm is triggered as a foreground service sounding an ringtone.

**Problem:**

However this application does not trigger at the exact time in doze mode.
It works if the application is open, in background or closed as long as the phone is not in doze.
If I manually wake the phone from doze after the set alarm time it triggers the services to start.

The Application have the permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

`POST_NOTIFICATIONS`, `SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM`, `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` is requested and checked during runtime.

The alarm is set with:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(Vocabulary.ALARM_OBJECT, alarm);
        Intent weatherAlarmSchedulerIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class)
                .putExtras(bundle)
                .putExtra(AlarmReceiver.BROADCAST_TYPE, AlarmReceiver.BROADCAST_TYPE_SCHEDULED_ALARM);
        weatherAlarmSchedulerIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmId, weatherAlarmSchedulerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli(), pendingIntent);
```

Services are started with
`context.startForegroundService(intent);`
and services calls the `startForeground(notification.hashCode(), notification);` method.

The web data retrieval service uses `sendBroadcast(dataRetrivalIntent);` to call the broadcastreceiver.

The permissions are checked with:
`requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM}, Vocabulary.PERMISSION_SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARMS);`

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
        activity.startActivity(intent);`
```

and

`requestPermissions(permissions, Vocabulary.PERMISSION_POST_NOTIFICATION);`

Still the alarm cant fire in doze. Why?